# How to select by two fields using IN operator

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, where-clause

I tried query like

```
SELECT id FROM events WHERE iid = 2 AND target_id = 3 OR iid = 3 AND target_id = 5 OR...
```

How to short this? Also tried to use IN operator but it get wrong logic

```
SELECT id FROM events where iid IN (2, 3) AND target_id IN (3, 5)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Postgres support tuples equality:

```
select id
from events
where (iid, target_id) in ( (2, 3), (3, 5) )
```